# Binding chain between textbox,listbox,observable collection not working

Tags: wpf, binding

I have a textbox bound to a listbox:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding ElementName=PasswordsBox, Path=SelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Name="PasswordBox"/>
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Processor.Passwords,ValidatesOnDataErrors=True,Mode=TwoWay}" Name="PasswordsBox" Grid.Row="1"/>
```

and a button, which adds the content of the textbox to the list, which the listbox is bound to:

```
<Button Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="3" Command="{Binding AddPasswordCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding Text, ElementName=PasswordBox}">+</Button>
```

The command is defined as following:

```
_addPasswordCommand = new DelegateCommand<string>((newPass) =>  Processor.Passwords.Add(newPass));
```

Here is the "Passwords" collection from the model:

```
public ObservableCollection<string> Passwords
   {
        get
        {
            return _passwords;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_passwords != value)
            {
                _passwords = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Passwords");
            }
        }
    }
```

But i can't even type something in the textbox. If i add an empty element with the command and select it, i can't edit it.

Answer (score 0):

Your textbox needs to bind to a property of listbox selecteditem, something like this

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding ElementName=PasswordsBox, Path=SelectedItem.Password, Mode=TwoWay}" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Name="PasswordBox"/>
```

Because the selected item is of type Password, and I assume then password class has a text property in it.

Comment: The Passwords property is just an ObservableCollection<string>. Note: In the case of my application this is no secruity problem ;)